# Are EGL extensions promoted to core still exposed via EGL_EXTENSIONS?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, egl

Are EGL extensions that were promoted to core (like [`EXT_platform_base`](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/extensions/EXT/EGL_EXT_platform_base.txt) & [`EXT_client_extensions`](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/extensions/EXT/EGL_EXT_client_extensions.txt) were in EGL 1.5) still exposed via the `EGL_EXTENSIONS` string?

I wasn't seeing anything obvious either way in section 2.8 of [the EGL 1.5 spec](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/specs/eglspec.1.5.pdf) ("Extensions").

I did turn up [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Registry/blob/main/docs/promoting.html#L36-L76) on the OpenGL Registry repository but there's no indication that it might cross-apply to EGL.